# can we have a query of "10 posts from every category in one request"?

Tags: mysql

We have a list of posts that belong a category.
can we have a query of "10 posts from every category in one request" ?
Or 
We have to query 10 posts for every category separately ?
thx

Comment: You can try with GROUP BY statement

Comment: Or you can try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and GROUP BY category, if you want one row for every category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fudge involving using GROUP_CONCAT to put all the post ids for a category together (you can add an order clause to this if you want), then substring_index to get the first 10 posts.

This is then joined back to the original table using FIND_IN_SET

```
SELECT a.*
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT category_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(post_id), ',', 10) AS posts
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY catgegory_id
) sub0
ON a.category_id = sub0.category_id
AND FIND_IN_SET(a.post_id, sub0.posts)
```

Or using variables:-

```
SELECT a.*
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT category_id, post_id, @cnt:=IF(@category_id=category_id, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt, @category_id:=category_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT category_id, post_id
        FROM some_table
        ORDER BY category_id, post_id
    ) sub0
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0, @category_id:=0) sub1
) sub2
ON a.category_id = sub2.category_id
AND a.post_id = sub2.post_id
AND cnt <= 10
```

Comment: Glad it works. Note the first one is a bit of a fudge as it is using GROUP_CONCAT (which is meant for strings really) on the integer id field.

Comment: but there is a note here. in this method, you are loading all of the table rows and match theme by some post ids. isn't there a better way for the same reason?

Comment: Both suffer that in some way but in MySQL not sure there is a real way round that. Possible there might be a way around it with a correlated sub query with a limit but not probably no better.

Comment: How do you want to narrow things down?

Answer (score 0):

This pseudo code should point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM T AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM T WHERE T.CATEGORY = T1.CATEGORY ORDER BY CATEGORY DESC LIMIT 10)
```